# Get UTF8 strings from remote DB

Tags: python, mysql, string, decoding

My application downloads some data from remote MySQL database. Problem is that db stores strings as utf8. But data I receive is ascii decoded. How to get around this ?

The code :

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
query = """MY QUERY HERE"""
cursor.execute(query)
result = cursor.fetchall()
```

Comment: what version are you using? Python3 has unicode strings by default. Does string.decode('utf-8') works?

Comment: I have 2.6 . Nope. Encoding doesn't change anything since result is ascii already.

Comment: I don't think you mean "ASCII decoded": That should work fine in UTF-8. What exactly is the problem you are having? Does data get scrambled? How?

Comment: I'm getting '?' for every polish-specific sign.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps an example is in order -- here I create a unicode string "u", encode it as utf8, decode that from utf8 back to a unicode string, encode it as ascii (which throws an exception since the extended character in this string can't be encoded as ascii), then finally encode as ascii replacing errors with the "?":

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Dec  7 2009, 18:43:55) 
[GCC 4.4.1] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> u = u'abc\u2020123'
>>> u
u'abc\u2020123'
>>> u.encode('utf8')
'abc\xe2\x80\xa0123'
>>> s = _
>>> s.decode('utf8')
u'abc\u2020123'
>>> u.encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2020' in position 3: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> u.encode('ascii', 'replace')
'abc?123'
>>>
```

Presumably, you're getting utf8 strings back from the db, you should decode these from utf8 to a unicode string, then probably re-encode them on output for whatever is consuming the output of your program...  Typically you want a model something like:

1. Input data  -- transform from input encoding to unicode [string.decode('utf8')]
2. Process data -- dealing only with unicode objects
3. Output result -- transform from unicode to output encoding [string.encode('utf8')]

This gives you a clean separation of encoding/decoding and avoids spreading encoding-handling code all over your application since the core only deals with unicode.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try `string.encode('ascii').decode('utf-8')`?

Answer (score 0):

do a `conn.set_character_encoding('utf8')` before querying from the db.

Answer (score -1):

just set your python to utf-8 encoding and you don't have to worry anymore. had this problem with db2/ mongodb to load data.

just set the defaultencoding to utf-8 under site.py.

have a look @ http://blog.ianbicking.org/illusive-setdefaultencoding.html

Comment: Then read http://tarekziade.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/syssetdefaultencoding-is-evil/ and http://bytes.com/topic/python/answers/699848-sys-setdefaultencoding.